# How to get upload progress info form http post request in node js?

Tags: node.js, http

I would like to get upload progress information during http post request using node js http.
my code is simple and it works but I am only notified when there is an error or the upload is completed.
But I need to show a progress bar to the user and to do that I need to check the progress every second or so.
Basically I need to have upload speed and how much of the file has been uploaded at given time.

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const FormData = require('form-data');

function myUploadFunction(authToken,uploadPath, file) {

    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('file', fs.createReadStream(file.path));
    form.append('filename', file.name);
    form.append('parent_dir', '/');
    const requestHeaders = {
        Accept: '*/*',
        Authorization: `Token ${authToken}`,
    };
    const options = {
        host: 'myHost',
        port: 'myPort',
        path: uploadPath,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: requestHeaders,
    };
    form.submit(options, (error, response) => {

        response.setEncoding('utf8');
        response.on('data', (chunk) => {
            // this code runs only when the upload is completed and the server only send some info about the file. And only if this info is large it will send it in chunks
            logger.debug(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
        });
        response.on('end', () => {
            logger.debug('No more data in response.');
        });
    });
}
```

When I upload a file, nothing happens till upload is completed then I get the response and it executes response.onData and afetr that response.onEnd.

Comment: I found a working example here: https://github.com/form-data/form-data/pull/56/files#diff-3b8080b944f5c64eb2514fe942b7c60fR60

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add another listener to handle the progress

```
    form.on('progress', (bytesReceived, bytesExpected)  => {
        logger.warn('progress bytesReceived: ', bytesReceived);
        logger.warn('progress bytesExpected: ', bytesExpected);
    });
```